# build solution error:error C2065: 'prpack_igraph_graph' : undeclared identifier \igraph-0.7.1-msvc\igraph-0.7.1-msvc\src\prpack.cpp

Tags: visual-studio-2013, igraph

I downloaded `igraph-0.7.1-msvc.zip` and opened `igraph.sln` in Visual Studio 2013, changed "bug" to "release", then built the solution. But it reports the following error :

```
IntelliSense: identifier "prpack_igraph_graph" is undefined \igraph-0.7.1-msvc\igraph-0.7.1-msvc\src\prpack.cpp 66  5   igraph
Error   312 error C2065: 'prpack_igraph_graph' : undeclared identifier  \igraph-0.7.1-msvc\igraph-0.7.1-msvc\src\prpack.cpp 66  1   igraph
Error   313 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'prpack_graph'    \igraph-0.7.1-msvc\igraph-0.7.1-msvc\src\prpack.cpp 66  1   igraph
Error   315 error C2065: 'prpack_graph' : undeclared identifier\igraph-0.7.1-msvc\igraph-0.7.1-msvc\src\prpack.cpp  67  1   igraph
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Tamas. 
The detailed steps should be: Goto Project menu -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line. In Additional options, add the following option: /DPRPACK_IGRAPH_SUPPORT=1

See more in my blog: http://dungleba.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/installing-igraph-in-visual-studio-2013/

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bug in the MSVC release of igraph; try adding `/DPRPACK_IGRAPH_SUPPORT=1` to the compiler options and then recompile.